# Calling another page without pageload after button click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I am fetching data from FB and storing in database. After processing completes I want to redirect to test.php wihout page reload. But I dont know how to do it for following complex(for me) code.

I have two function.

```
function AjaxResponse()
 {
    var mydata;
    CallAfterLogin(mydata, function(send) {
    alert(mydata);
        var myData = 'connect=1'; 
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_facebook2.php",
        data: mydata 
        }).done(function(result) {
                        $("#fb-root").html(result);
                     });
               });
  }
```

and

```
function CallAfterLogin(data,callback){
        FB.login(function(response) {  //---
        if (response.status === "connected")
        {
            LodingAnimate(); 
            FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email', function(mydata) {
            console.log(mydata);
              if(mydata.email == null)
              {
                 alert("You must allow us to access your email id!");
                 ResetAnimate();
              }

              else 
        {
            var json = JSON.stringify(mydata.movies.data);
            var a = JSON.parse(json);

            $.post('process_facebook2.php',{'myd':a}, function(data) 
            {
              alert(data);      
            });
        }
```

Which called by :

```
<input type="image" src="fb.png" name="getStarted" value="btnBasic1" onclick="AjaxResponse()" height="40" alt="Submit" />
```

After `alert(data)` i want it to redirect to some page test.php. How it possible wihout page reload?

Answer (score 0):

You could load the content you want to change via jQuery with [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what test.php contains you could do an AJAX call to load test.php and replace the body of the current page with jQuery.

test.php

```
$new_body = '<h1>Hi!</h1>';
echo $new_body;
```

AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
url:        'test.php'
,async:     true
,cache:     false
,dataType:  'html'
,success:   function(data){
                $('body').html(data);
            }
});
```